# Can we use IBM MQ in C# Client Server application?

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a Client-Server application, please find details below.

1. Client : C# Client (Windows Forms)
2. Service : C# Server (Remoting)
3. Backend : SQL Server 2014

Can we utilize IBM MQ for sending messages from the above application to a Linux machine("**IBM MQ 9.1.0.7 for RHEL server**")?

Is this possible? If so, do we need to utilize "**IBM MQ 9.2.0.1 Client for Windows**"?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=programs-example-c-code-fragment-use-net, 2 : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=net-sample-applications

Comment: Yes it is possible.   You can pull the required. .NET core MQ dlls from NuGet.

Comment: You may want to read the [IBM MQ .NET Primer](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6879) I posted the other day.